# Import CSV file into Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I tried several times to import CSV file into python 2.7.15 but it fail.
Please suggest how to import CSV in Python.

[image: csv into python]

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways to import a csv file in Python.

First: Using standard Python `csv`

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_read=csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
```

Second: Using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
data.head() # to display the first 5 lines of loaded data
```

I would suggest to import using `pandas` since that's the more convenient way to do so.

Comment: i ll try ur code , thanks mr Leon

Comment: i try the first standard code - but nothing print on screen. and i try the second code - panda - but there is an error ( Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas )

Comment: Yes first you have to install pandas using your python terminal.

Comment: Enter pip install pandas to do so...

Comment: 'pip install pandas'

Comment: i ll install it , thanks mr Leon .

Comment: Are you using an IDE or Terminal?

Comment: i had setup most of library , and i use IDE , but still i cann't import the file , what is ur suggetion mr Leon ?

Comment: Is the file in your project folder?..it has to be in your project folder..

Comment: I suppose this link will also help you..."https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_dataframe_importing_csv/"

Comment: https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_dataframe_importing_csv

Comment: i ll try it , thank u Mr Leon .